# The physics behind the circle / spiral of fifths

Tags: waves, acoustics, frequency, wavelength

In music theory, there is this thing called the circle of fifths.
If you take a string, and you divide it in two equal parts, you get a so called octave. It is, to our ear, kind of "the same tone", without some of the base resonances.

Now, if we divide the string in three equal parts, we get the so called fifth. Now, if you take the fifth, and make it an octave deeper (ie double the length) (just for the sake of keeping things in a practical range for the ears), and then divide it in three again, you have the next fifth.

If you keep repeating this process, you will almost get back to the original tone after twelve iterations. This is the circle of fifths (C - G - D- A - E- B - F* - C* - G* - Eb - Bb - F - C). But in reality its a spiral, i.e. you don't come back to C, but a little distance away from it.

I never found or heard an explanation for this, but I would be very interested.

Comment: What would an acceptable explanation look like here?  Mathematically, it's because $(3/2)^{12}\approx129.746 \approx 2^7$, so we span *just over* 7 octaves in twelve steps of perfect fifths, and no other powers of 3/2 are all that close to a power of 2. But barring some neurological explanation for why our brains "like" frequency ratios of small integers, all of this stuff is incredibly psycho-sociologically contingent.  For instance, the choice of twelve equal-ish steps for notes in an octave is a "social construct". There's not a *lot* of physics here.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I guess it's  that simple that its just because 3 to the power of integer x will never be 2 to the power of integer y. Hm. Funny. Maybe it was a stupid question? 
Anyways Ill have to reflect on how much of this is physics, how much of it is just culture. Somehow I always thought that the spiral of fifths was part of the nature of the universe or so, but maybe it's not as fancy as all that.

Comment: I have some info about rational approximations of $\log_2 3$ here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3983124/207316

Comment: The music SE has numerous posts on this & related topics,  eg https://music.stackexchange.com/q/49819

Answer (score 1):

There are physiological reasons why the octave (2:1 ratio) and the perfect fifth (3:2 ratio) sound particularly harmonious to the human ear. The perfect fourth (4:3 ratio) also sounds harmonious, and can be constructed by inverting the perfect fifth interval to get a 2:3 ratio then transposing the lower note up by one octave.

The twelve tones of [Pythagorean tuning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_tuning), created from successive perfect fifth intervals, are based on the mathematical fact that $(\frac 3 2)^{12} \approx 2^7$. This was discovered by the Ancient Mesopotamians and subsequently borrowed by the Ancient Greeks. It was also discovered independently by the Chinese, so it seems a fairly natural way to accommodate perfect fifths and (approximate) octaves in a single scale. However, it is not the only way - alternatives include [5-limit tuning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-limit_tuning) and [7-limit tuning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-limit_tuning).

Twelve-tone equal temperament, which achieves equal ratios between the twelve successive tones at the price of approximating the perfect fifth, is a fairly recent invention, being independently invented in China and Europe in the 16th century.

You don't even have to stick to twelve tones within an octave. For example, 20th century composer Harry Partch advocated a microtonal system in which the octave is divided into [43 tones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Partch%27s_43-tone_scale).